# Read single file from ZIP within a directory

Tags: php, zip, wrapper

I have a ZIP file (with a VPK extension) and I wish to extract a file that is within a directory of the zip file. The uploaded file uploads correctly. Here is my current code. but unfortunately it throws up an error.

```
$hbid =  substr(md5(time()),0,16);
mkdir("pkg/".$hbid, 0700);
mkdir("pkg_image/".$hbid, 0700);
$target_dir = "pkg/" . $hbid . "/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
...
FILE UPLOADING CODE HERE
...

ERROR -> $handle = fopen('zip://./'.$target_file.'#/sce_sys/icon0.png', 'r'); 

$result = '';
if($handle){
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $result .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
$file = fopen("pkg_image/".$hbid."/icon0.png");
fwrite($file,$result);
fclose($file);
```

The error code is this:

```
fopen(zip://./pkg/0152cc9c0c52da70/4rows_1_1.vpk#/sce_sys/icon0.png): failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I've never extracted a file this way before but looking at other answers related to this, they all extract a file from the root of the zip, but the file I need is in a subdirectory of the zip file. I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The correction is to replace the /sce_sys with #sce_sys. The initial / is not required for a directory.